# File Location and Unknown Error JAVAFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to construct a basic UI with javafx and i have done this several time before. For some reason i have encountered this:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at Main.Main.start(Main.java:18)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
```

Exception running application Main.Main

I don't understand what i am doing wrong as this has never happened to me and i have repeated this process in the same way as to previous.
Photo of eclipse layout:
https://gyazo.com/b77d2ceace61eef8ed2526686f6763f0?token=d3f747ca001b7e411d721c12cd54b46a 
Code:
Main.java:

```
package Main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane mainPane = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("Main.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

myController.java:

```
package Main;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class myController {

@FXML
private TextField quantity;

@FXML
private Button adding;

@FXML
private ScrollBar currentP;

@FXML
private Label message;

@FXML
private ComboBox<?> stocks;

@FXML
private Button remove;

@FXML
void itemPicked(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void getIndexC(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void deleteItem(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void addItem(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void getQuantity(ActionEvent event) {

}

}
```

Main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" stylesheets="@myStyle.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="myController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="568.0" fitWidth="684.0" layoutX="356.0" layoutY="167.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../Pictures/builder.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="885.0" fitWidth="857.0" layoutX="629.0" layoutY="187.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="90.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../Pictures/Uroburos-rootkit-Espionage-Russia.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="885.0" fitWidth="857.0" layoutX="-187.0" layoutY="187.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="90.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../Pictures/Uroburos-rootkit-Espionage-Russia.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Line endX="100.0" endY="400.0" layoutX="381.0" layoutY="324.0" startX="100.0" startY="-325.0" />
      <Line endX="425.0" endY="390.0" layoutX="391.0" layoutY="334.0" startX="425.0" startY="-335.0" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="stocks" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="135.0" onAction="#itemPicked" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="421.0" promptText="Please Select and Item" />
      <ScrollBar fx:id="currentP" layoutX="857.0" layoutY="108.0" onDragDetected="#getIndexC" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
      <Button fx:id="remove" layoutX="1007.0" layoutY="53.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteItem" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="250.0" text="Remove From Order">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <ImageView fitHeight="72.0" fitWidth="79.0" layoutX="491.0" layoutY="74.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../Pictures/Uroburos-rootkit-Espionage-Russia.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="491.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="311.0" text="RootKit At your Service" textAlignment="JUSTIFY">
         <font>
            <Font name="Courier New Bold Italic" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="message" layoutX="587.0" layoutY="87.0" text="&quot;Protecting&quot; your trade">
          <font>
            <Font name="Courier New Italic" size="15.0" />
          </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="adding" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="81.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addItem" text="Add Item To Order">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <TextField fx:id="quantity" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="194.0" onAction="#getQuantity" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="62.0" promptText="&quot;1&quot;">
         <font>
           <Font size="20.0" />
         </font></TextField>
      <Label layoutX="108.0" layoutY="196.0" text="Quantity" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="34.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

CSS File is currently empty.
I want to overall get the GUI displaying but for some reason the location is not found and for some reason i have another error which i cannot even identify.
Thanks for all help in advance <3

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.

Comment: The exception means the `FXMLLoader` can't find the FXML in the expected location (it should be in the same package as the `Main` class).

Answer (score 0):

In your FXML file, your controller needs to be `Main.myController`. The controller specification needs to be fully qualified.

Comment: All very true, but that's not what's causing the exception that was posted in the question.

Comment: That's strange... I setup the project as the OP had and didn't get the location error

Comment: Are you sure? It will work if the FXML file is in the `Main` package, but it looks like he has it in the root of the classpath. Compare your layout really carefully... If the difference is there you can add that to your answer.